# Return minimum date values for each employee with variable number of sales

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to write a formula that will compare the dates of sales to dates of follow-up contact within three days of the sale.

For example, given the data below:

```
            Follow-Up      Sale

Jim         06/15/2019     06/14/2019
Jim                        06/19/2019

Dwight                     06/06/2019
Dwight                     06/09/2019
Dwight      06/04/2019     06/11/2019
Dwight                     06/12/2019
Dwight                     06/15/2019

Michael     06/13/2019
Michael                    06/04/2019
Michael                    06/07/2019

Phyllis     06/18/2019     06/18/2019
```

I would expect to see:

```
            3 Day Contact?

Jim         1
Dwight      0
Michael     0
Phyllis     1
```

I obviously need an array that loops through the Sale dates, but I am lost as to how to break it up for each person.

All I have so far is:

```
=IF(AND(MIN([[Follw-up] - {Sales}) =< 3, MIN([Follow-up] - {Sales}) >= 0), 1, 0)
```

And I am stuck on the {Sales} portion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: do you have control over how the data is formatted?  Can the follow up call be made the first entry?  Can there be more than one follow up call?

Answer (score 0):

one convoluted (ugly) approach is the following:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$5:$B$18,G4,$D$5:$D$18,"<="&INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($B$5:$B$18)/(($B$5:$B$18=G4)*($C$5:$C$18<>"")),1)),$D$5:$D$18,">="&INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($B$5:$B$18)/(($B$5:$B$18=G4)*($C$5:$C$18<>"")),1))-3)
```

Basically it uses COUNTIFS, INDEX and AGGREGATE.  COUNTIFS is used to match the name of the person found to the left, all dates that are less than the sales call date found by the INDEX/AGGREGATE combo, and all dates that are great than or equal to 3 days before the sale call found by the INDEX/AGGREGATE combo.

[image: POC]